# Error bound for a PDE with a perturbation term

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

In ODE theory, if we have
$$y' = f(t, y),\ y(0) = c$$
and
$$x' = f(t, x)+g(t, x),\ x(0) = c+d$$
we are able to say that $|x(t)-y(t)|<m|g(t)|+n|d|$.

Is there an analogy theorem in PDE? Suppose I have a second-order linear parabolic pde
$$u_t = Lu,\ u(x, 0) = u_0(x)$$

Consider a similar pde with a perturbation term
$$\hat u_t = L\hat u+f(x,t),\ \hat u(x, 0) = u_0(x)+g(x)$$

Are we able to solve the bound of $|u-\hat u|$?

Update:

My target pde is [black-scholes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation). Its domain is $[0,\infty]\times [0, T]$ where T is a constant. And the $[0,\infty]$ can be truncated to $[0, S_{Max}]$.

Comment: What you are looking for a standard estimates for parabolic equations. Usually you have some restrictions on the operator (especially a lower bound on the differential part) and the domain.

Comment: @maxmilgram Sorry I didn't realize that. My target pde is [black-scholes equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation). Its domain is $[0,\infty]\times [0, T]$ where T is a constant. And the $[0,\infty]$ can be truncated to $[0, S_{Max}]$.